# Why covariance is needed in the following example?

Tags: kotlin, generics

This might be a dumb question but I cannot wrap my head around this example:

```
open class Case<T> {}
class InheritedCase: Case<Nothing>()
fun getCase(): Case<out String> = InheritedCase()
```

Can someone explain why `out` must be specified and why a compile error is thrown when only using `String`?

Comment: Why do you think it is not needed?

Comment: @Sweeper 'out ' is needed and I don't understand why because when you declare a generic type without any variance(invariant) that means you have a producer as well as a consumer of T.

Comment: So...? A "producer and consumer" of `Nothing` is not a "producer and consumer" of `String`. The former can consume nothing, but the latter can consume strings. On the other hand, a producer of `Nothing` *is* a producer of `String` (this is what adding `out` says).

Comment: @Sweeper how can a producer of `Nothing` also be a producer of `String`?
I think a producer of `Any` can be a producer of `String`

Comment: A producer of `Any` is not a producer of `String`. It can produce anything, not just strings! Note that you should interpret "is a" as "can be classified as". A producer of `Nothing` produces nothing, so it can be classified as a producer of strings, or a producer of integers, or a producer of characters, or whatever you want. It's the same logic as "an empty list can be classified as a list of strings if you don't add anything to it"

Comment: When thinking about `Nothing` as a generic type, it helps to think of it as a subtype of every possible type. The logic works out.

Comment: This isn't a very good example, because the class has no methods (and so the type parameter is never used). If it had a method taking a `T` parameter — and/or one returning a `T` — then things might be clearer. (And note that in practice, you rarely need to specify `in` or `out` on variables, because the type parameters are usually declared that way where appropriate.)